# Date not being displayed in title

Tags: titles

Could anyone tell me why the date is not being shown in the title of my document. The document class is `proc`. If I remove `\date{\today}` my title moves down a return, but no date is displayed when I leave it in.

```
\title{Title}
\author{Me\\
        Email\\}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
```

Answer (score 7):

This may be due to the definition of `\maketitle` not containing date. So, you might want to check out where you have `\def\@maketitle` (it may be in your style file/document class). After finding the definition, you can insert date into it.

The `proc` document class doesn’t typeset the date in `\maketitle`:

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \vbox to 2.25in{%
    \hsize\textwidth
    \linewidth\hsize
    \vfil
    \centering
    {\LARGE \@title \par}
    \vskip 2em
    {\large \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@author \end{tabular}\par}
    \vfil}}
```

Contrast it with the `article` document class:

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    {\large \@date}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
```

Comment: This answer does not makes clear how to change the setting on Overleaf.